# Issue with a uncooperative player

Tags: dnd-5e, problem-players

So we have a good campaign goin, second with this group though some of them joined mid-way through the last campaign. Though not entirely important to this question, it's a D&D 5e campaign.

That said, one of our original players, from the inception of this group, is the typical min-maxer type, which wasn't an issue until this new campaign. Now he seems to purposely derail things. The whole party agrees on a course of action, then at the last minute he goes off and gets his character into an unrelated situation, prompting the players to follow to save him, for example. The DM seems to want him gone, but doesn't want to actually confront him.

The group consists of 5 players + the DM. In my 30 + years of gaming, I've never dealt with a player like this. I understand not agreeing with other player choices and opinions, but to constantly be counter productive seems pointless. The DM sees the issue and asks me how I feel about it, but that's where it ends. Nothing is done about it, other than some post game comments I've made, as well as my character pointing it out to his. The reactions are always just a shrug.

How would you deal with a player like this?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] when you get a chance. This question needs more information before we can answer it. How big is your group? What have you tried to deal with the issue? The more information you can provide the better we can help. Thanks for participating and happy gaming!

Comment: 5 players + DM. I've said something personally after game, after my character has reacted to his character. He just shrugs everything off.its as if he doesn't really want to do anything but roll.dice in combat, yet he develops tons of back story and it points for DM use.

Comment: To add to this, if I were the DM I would speak to the player privately and explain that this is a game of cooperative story telling, and the big picture pay off is for everyone, not just the DM. But my DM does not seem to be willing to have this type of chat.

Comment: If your DM is not willing to have this conversation you may have more of an issue with them than the player. I suggest you [edit] in information about how the DM refuses to handle it.

Comment: Can you share what, if any, solutions you have tried? Also check out the [**problem-players**] tag on this site.  There are lots of great questions and answers that apply to your situation.

Comment: Is this issue significant enough that you've considered leaving the group? Is that an option or are there issue that could arise from that? What's your relationship with the other players—are they friends, family, buddies from work?

Comment: The other players feel the same way, but are unwilling to speak up. I am not sure why this is, as we are all adults in our 40's. The reason I actually reacted to the situation is because everyone has been complaining behind his back about it.

Comment: I could leave the group, but I won't. We are all friends through the formation of this group, but for the DM and I who were friends prior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is talk to him. Mention that his playing style is getting frustrating. Make sure he knows that his behavior is impacting your fun. Expelling him from the group should be the last resort, not the first.

If he knows that his playstyle is frustrating you, but continues, talk to the other players. He may just be grating to you, at which point you might be the bad guy for trying to get him kicked out over incompatible personalities. See if the party is also frustrated by his actions, and if any of them can talk him out of his playing style. If nobody gets through to him, make it clear that he won't be supported in his one-sided acts. Don't start out by letting him solo the dragon, but don't go out of your way to heal him. Make him buy his own stuff. Make him sit in jail for a few days when he screws up. If he gets that he can't dominate the game without consequences, he may reform, or quit by himself and look for a different game.

If he insists on derailing and drawing attention and forcing the story to follow his min-maxed character, let the character die. Maybe his character is the one who's abrasive and domineering, and a new character might have a more manageable personality. Or it might be the final straw and he quits himself.

And of course, the DM's job is to make sure people are having fun in his story. If the DM knows that the rest of the players want the minmaxer gone, it makes it a lot easier to drop him.

Comment: The other players feel the same way, but are unwilling to speak up. I am not sure why this is, as we are all adults in our 40's. The reason I actually reacted to the situation is because everyone has been complaining behind his back about it.

Comment: Talk to them. Work with them. Maybe there's a reason why they're not speaking to him directly. If you all agree that it's getting intolerable and nobody expects him to change, talk with the DM and ALL of you can make a decision to do something about him.

Comment: I will do just that at tomorrow's session, as the player in question will be absent. We've discussed via Hangouts, but I think an in-person discussion needs to happen.